# How to remove duplicate columns in CSV file using Java

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I have a Java program that is getting a CSV file from an API and inserting the data to my database.

The API response is giving some duplicate columns.
Here is the current response:

```
Name   Email   PhoneNo   Address   BankAcc   Name   AccType   PhoneNo   CreditScore   Address   State
```

This is causing failure in data insertion.

Now I want to read the CSV file, delete the duplicate columns and save it back using Java. The resulting CSV file should be like this:

```
Name   Email   PhoneNo   Address   BankAcc   AccType   CreditScore   State
```

Comment: Is the first line of every CSV file a Header Line indicating the column names and do the duplicated columns show in this Header Line?

Comment: Yes, first line contains the column names as shown in the question and the duplicate column names also show up there.

I know the approach to solve this would be to note down the index of the header and skip all those in that index. It's just that I am not able to program it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are the data in both the address column same? if yes, when you parse the response csv file you can ignore duplicate column

Comment: Yes, I do know that but I couldn't figure out how to turn it into code.